# Is it ok to send the data received from the client to php with ajax in node js?

Tags: javascript, php, node.js, ajax, wordpress

I am developing a project, a wordpress plugin. And I have to do instant transactions, so I wanted to use websocket instead of ajax.I run node.js with socket.io on my server server now everything goes well. But how do I send the data coming to the node.js server to php? I ran an ajax query for this, on the node.js side, how correct is this usage. I also tried some derivatives such as elephant.io and I couldn't send data to socket.io with php.

I've been searching for almost 2 days, but the sources I found are always old and I could not come to a conclusion so I decided to ask here.

1. How do I transfer the data sent from the client to node.js to php and get the returned data.
2. How do I send data from PHP to socket.io or socket.io to PHP?
3. Is it logical to send the data sent from the client via websocket to the php page with ajax in node.js?

In fact, the 3 questions I ask are in the same place, except for the basic differences, can you help me with this?

Yes, I can now send data to the client with a php page. But how do I capture the data from the client here.

```php
require __DIR__ . '/vendor/autoload.php';

use ElephantIO\Client;
use ElephantIO\Engine\SocketIO\Version2X;

$client = new Client(new Version2X('http://localhost:3000'));

$client->initialize();
$client->emit('server_way', ['foo' => 'bar']);
$client->close();

if ( isset( $_GET['action'] ) ) {
    echo $_GET['action'];
}
```

```
const ajax_url = 'http://localhost/projeler/bp-instant-message-socket-io-core/socket.php';

const http = require('http').createServer();
const io = require('socket.io')(http,{
    cors: {
        origin: "http://localhost",
        methods: ["GET", "POST"]
    }
});
var $ = require('jquery')(require('jsdom-no-contextify').jsdom().parentWindow);
var XMLHttpRequest = require("xmlhttprequest").XMLHttpRequest;
$.support.cors = true;
$.ajaxSettings.xhr = function () {
    return new XMLHttpRequest;
}

io.on('connection', (socket) => {

    console.log("biri bağlandı");

    socket.on('server_way', (data) => {
        console.log(data);
        io.emit('client_way',data);
    });

    socket.on('disconnect',function(){
        console.log("biri ayrıldı");
    });

});
  
http.listen(3000, () => {
    console.log('listening on *:3000');
});
```

Comment: Something like: https://zeromq.org/ ?

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan Yes, I guess I am writing an instant two-sided messaging system and ajax queries create a huge load, I wanted to use a websocket to prevent this, but now I have not been successful. Since I'm going to make a WordPress plugin, I need to send the incoming data to a php page and get a feedback. I did this with ajax, but I didn't know how accurately. https://prnt.sc/wo8e2w

Comment: PHP supports websockets too...

Comment: @ADyson Yes, I know I searched a lot, but I couldn't find how to do it, none of the examples I found worked, I don't think it's a mistake. Elephant.io port will give an error if it is closed, if it is open, it will not give an error, but it will not send the data. The data I receive from the client first comes to node.js and I have to send the data coming to node.js to php somehow I used ajax for this, but is it healthy? I do not know.

Comment: That's a subjective question. If it meets your requirements and has no downsides (or none that you care about) then why not do it like that? As an architect I'd say it's inefficient to have backends in 2 separate languages when you could use PHP for both (e.g. Ratchet implements a websocket server in PHP) but it's always a trade-off of some sort. We can't say to you "yes you must do it like that", all you'll get is opinions and suggestions...and those kinds of questions are not really the type this site deals with - "opinion-based" is a specific reason you can vote to close a question.

Comment: Also, we don't really know what the data is or precisely what needs to happen to it. e.g. you say "send it to PHP"....but for what purpose? Will PHP process it in some way and give a response back to the user? Or will the data maybe just be stored in a database? If it's the latter, for example, you could have nodeJS just write the data directly to the same database that PHP uses. But if you need feedback to the user, you might have to think more carefully. There are many ways to skin a cat, as the saying goes...

Comment: BTW one thing you said was confusing: _"I ran an ajax query for this, on the node.js side"_ ...but it doesn't make sense because only browsers can make AJAX requests. If you make a request which is triggered by server-side code, then that's just a regular HTTP request, not AJAX.

Comment: @ADyson Yes, I thought that if I establish a direct mysql connection with nodeJS, I can do the operations from here, but since I aim to sell this product, it may not meet the market standards of envato. I also want to keep it simple during installation, which can scare users.

Comment: I added my NodeJs code

Comment: I don't know anything about envato, so I can't advise you on that. You'd have to check their standards, if they're published. Since you mentioned you're trying to integrate this with wordpress specifically, might it be worth seeing if there are more direct ways to connect websockets to PHP in a wordpress-specific way? e.g. I found this tutorial (but there are others) https://www.soliddigital.com/blog/wordpress-and-websockets by simply googling "wordpress websockets". I would expect you will want to simplify your server-side installation as much as possible.

Comment: As you said yes, I want to avoid complexity and simplify it because the easier use and better performance, the more customers I see. I will search the way you say, I have always searched for php websocket, not wordpress.

Comment: @ADyson Yes, I am sending data to the socket with php, I also achieved this. But I have a problem :D Well, how do I send the data in the socket to the php page, I can only think of ajax because I know it.